# Making a popup to open at the position where the mouse is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
            $("#hidePopup").dialog({
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                position: { my: "right top", at: "right bottom", of: $("#hideCross")},
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: true,
            }).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

The code for rendering a pop-up in my web looks like this.
How can change the position to make it pop-up on a clicked position?
How do I have to change my position: part?

Answer (score 10):

try this code

```js
$(window).click(function(e) {
  $(".popup").css({left: e.pageX});
  $(".popup").css({top: e.pageY});
  $(".popup").show();
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup" style="">
   Popup text...
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't handle case when clicking at edge

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to open the dialog box at clicked position. In order to get the position you have to use the click event track the position of the mouse see examble code below.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    $("#Dialogid").dialog("option", { position: [e.pageX, e.pageY] });
});
```

The above code will open your dialog at click position